# Scrape json objects that start with [some text]

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BS4 to scape an eCommerce site and I need to check the stock.
Most of the products I can check the stock scraping the product json for:

```
stock = (jsonData['stocks']['XZ32_'])
```

because the json object is something like:

```
"stocks": {
  "XZ32_": 81
}
```

But sometimes it changes and looks something like this:

```
"stocks": {
  "XZ32_33935": 81
}
```

This number changes on every single product.

**Question:** Is there any way to get the value for a key in the json object that starts with "XZ32_" ?

Comment: Has `"stocks"` dictionary only one `"XZ32_*"` key or could there be more?

Comment: @AndrejKesely only one "XZ32_*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example to get value of key that starts with `XZ32_`:

```
jsonData = {
    "stocks": {
      "XZ32_33935": 81
    }
}

xz32 = next(jsonData['stocks'][k] for k in jsonData['stocks'] if k.startswith('XZ32_'))
print(xz32)
```

Prints:

```
81
```

---

More elaborate example (returns `default` if no key is found):

```
jsonData = {
    "stocks": {
      "XZ32_33935": 81
    }
}

def get_value(d, key_start, default=None):
    for k in d:
        if k.startswith(key_start):
            return d[k]
    return default

x32 = get_value(jsonData['stocks'], 'XZ32_')
print(x32)
```